# How to make React app show the state immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm making a simple interest calculator, and I want it to calculate the interest immediately after the user fills in all the required fields.

The problem is that the when I calculate the interest and call setResult(theInterest) it doesn't show the result immediately, I have to type another number in one of the fields so the result updates, but then it will show the result based on the previous numbers (the previous result) not the new one.

Here is a link to my code:
https://github.com/abdulaziz-sama/Interest-Calculator/blob/master/src/App.jsx

Comment: Please create a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) (also possible with [React](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support)) instead of sending people to an external site. The link may break in the future making the question more or less irrelevent for future readers.

Comment: Please add your code here. Also, I had a look where are you checking for your result?

Comment: This is a perfect example of when to use `useEffect`. I've also fixed your labels (you need to use `htmlFor` and also set the `id` for the inputs) and your calculation: https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-meadow-ebgov?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

Use `useEffect` to trigger the `calculteInterest` function as you have state changes that rerender your component within your handleChange function.

it would look something like this:

```js
useEffect(calculteInterest, [principal, rate, time])
```

And remove the function call from your handleChange function.

codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-dust-zgkkz?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the set method of the useState is running asynchronously.

Here is the working code:

```
function Calculator() {
  const [result, setResult] = useState(0);
  const [principal, setPrincipal] = useState(0);
  const [rate, setRate] = useState(0);
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0);

  // This is just to show the async behaviour.
  const [test, setTest] = useState(0);

  function handleChange(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    // Putting "+" before a string converts it to a number ✨JS magic.
    // But here we're testing if it's a valid number. If not we're not going to set anything.
    if (Number.isNaN(+value)) {
      return;
    }

    // We are sure that the +value is a valid number so we're setting that to the state.
    if (name === "principal") {
      setPrincipal(+value);
    } else if (name === "rate") {
      setRate(+value);
    } else if (name === "time") {
      setTime(+value);
    }
  }

  // This effect will run everytime principal, rate or time changes.
  // We dont need to convert values since we're always storing numbers in the states.
  useEffect(() => {
    var theInterest = principal * (rate / 100) * time;
    setResult(theInterest);
  }, [principal, rate, time]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Calculate Simple Interest</h1>

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setTest(test + 1);
          setTest(test + 1);
          setTest(test + 1);
        }}
      >
        test {test}
      </button>

      <label htmlFor="principal"> Initial Amount of Money: </label>
      <input
        onChange={handleChange}
        type="number"
        name="principal"
        step="any"
        placeholder="Enter Initial Amount"
        value={principal}
      />

      <label htmlFor="rate">Annual Interest Rate: </label>
      <input
        onChange={handleChange}
        type="number"
        name="rate"
        step="any"
        placeholder="Enter the rate"
        value={rate}
      />

      <label htmlFor="time">Time (in years):</label>
      <input
        onChange={handleChange}
        type="number"
        name="time"
        placeholder="Enter the period"
        value={time}
      />

      <h2>The interest is: {result}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I added a test button in here, so you can see the behaviour of the setTest. I try to increment it 3 times but it will only do it once. That is because the 3 calls run at the same time and they do not see the other ones modifying it too.

Also change the "for" attributes on labels to be "htmlFor".